# Is the function $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(x, y) = 7x + 3y$ injective? surjective?

Tags: functions

Define the mapping $\ \ f:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\ $ by $\ f(x,y) = 7x + 3y$.

Show by example that $\,f\,$ is not one-to-one.
Is $\ f$ a surjection? $\ $Compute $\ f^{\tiny{-1}\ \ \ \ }\ (\{16\})\ $ and $\ f^{\tiny{-1}\ \ \ \ }\ (\{11\})$

I have been trying to do the function for single $\,f(x)\,$ only. I really have no idea on double function like $\,f(x,y)\,$ – can someone show me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you study the function numerically, you would, for example, see that $f(1,8) = f(4,1) = 31$ and that would answer the first part of the question.

Comment: Clearly f is not a subjection! Can you ever have f(x,y) = 1? Also f(6,1) = f(3,8) so f is not injective too!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In order to find $f^{-1}(16)$, you can simply solve the equation $16=7x+3y$, for $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$. Same idea applies for finding $f^{-1}(11)$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is not one-to-one. For, the equation $7x+3y = 38$ admits at least these two positive-integer solutions $(x,y) = (5,1), (2,8)$.

The function $f$ is not surjective. For, the equation $7x+3y=1$ is not solvable in positive integers.

The last two questions require you to solve the equations $7x+3y = 16$ and $7x+3y = 11$ in positive integers, respectively. You can try these ones yourself. Well, for example, the pair $(x,y) = (1,3) \in \mathbb{N}$ and such that $7x + 3y = 16$; and no other pair of positive integers delivers the equation. So $f^{-1}\{ 16 \} = \{ (1, 3) \}$.

Comment: Does it mean that I have to find the value of x and y?

Comment: Yes it does :). I am sure you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not surjective since $\ f(m,n)\geq 10 \ \  \forall\  (m,n)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$,  and hence $ f(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})\neq \mathbb{N}$. Also $3\cdot8+7\cdot1=3\cdot1+7\cdot4=31$ so the function is not one one.